# MDX - StrToMember in Range

Tags: format, range, mdx, dateadd

I'm quite newbie using MDX, I use it in Power BI in order to create different reports.

I'm actually stuck with an issue after a lot of research in different pages, related to Time Ranges.

In the Cube there is a dimension [Time].[Date].[Date], that goes from **2014** to **2020**, so I figure out after many hours that all the options using Current Member wouldn't work.

I need to capture a Measure in the last 7, 30, 60, 90 days.

I found two options:

**OPTION 1. Using WITH and Member:**

```
`WITH MEMBER [Measures].x AS SUM  
({[Time].[Date].&[20190216]:[Time].[Date].&[20190222])
},[Measures].[Avg Loaned])

SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].x} on 0
,NON EMPTY ([Time].[Date].[Date]) on 1
FROM [MYCUBE]
WHERE (Some Conditions...)`
```

**OPTION 2. Using WITH, Range and Member**

```
`WITH 
SET [Range] AS
{[Time].[Date].&[20190216]:[Time].[Date].&[20190222]}
MEMBER [Measures].x AS SUM  
   ({nonempty([Range]*[Measures].[Avg Loaned])})  

SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].x} on 0
,NON EMPTY ([Time].[Date].[Date]) on 1
FROM [MYCUBE]
WHERE (Some Conditions...)`
```

In both cases I get the correct results, and it seems to keep working if I replace

```
**[Time].[Date].&[20190222]** --> StrToMember("[Time].[Date].&[" + Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") + "]")
```

But it doesn't work when I replace the first date

```
**[Time].[Date].&[20190216]** --> StrToMember('[Time].[Date].&[' + Format(dateadd('d',-7,Now()), 'YYYYMMDD') + "]")
```

**OR**

```
**[Time].[Date].&[20190216]** --> StrToMember('[Time].[Date].&[' + Format(dateadd('d',-7,cdate(Now())), 'YYYYMMDD') + "]")
```

**OR**

```
**[Time].[Date].&[20190216]** --> StrToMember('[Time].[Date].&[' + Format(cstr(dateadd('d',-7,Now())), 'YYYYMMDD') + "]")
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to accomplish the task, OPTION 1 or 2, but the main roadblock is how I'm writting down the starting limit for the range trying to use dateadd.

Thanks in advance, I know that there are many posts about this, I tried to adapt the examples to my code but I failed and after some days I'm not sure what could be the issue.

Rgds
Pablo

Answer (score 2):

In your working example you have StrToMember(" and in non-working example you have StrToMember(', so probably you should use double quotes and not single quotes: StrToMember("[Time].[Date].&["...